# Abaqus Python getByBoundingBox command

Tags: python, abaqus

I have a 2D part in Abaqus with many partitions and I therefore want to select many edges with the getByBoundingBox command to create a surface set. This is the bit of code I have:

```
p = mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Plate']
s = p.edges
edges = s.getByBoundingBox((0,0.02,0,0.003,0.04,0))
p.Surface(side1Edges=edges, name='r1')
```

But it gives me the following error: "edges = s.getByBoundingBox((0,0.02,0,0.003,0.04,0)) TypeError: arg1; found tuple, expecting float".

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corners of the bounding box should be provided as 6 separate numbers and not as a single tuple. The solution is very simple, just change the leading "((" and trailing "))" to single "(" and ")". So the call looks like this s.getByBoundingBox(0,0.02,0,0.003,0.04,0).

Comment: Thanks. CAE now crashes when I use the single bracket. I thought it might be because of zmin and zmax both being 0 (although in 2D they are both 0), but changing this doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

this comes quite late but in case anyone enters and has the same doubt:

When telling to Abaqus which edge/face/element you are actually selecting, sometimes you need to specify the "ID" of that object, that's why it's asking for a float instead of a tuple in the error message. This can be solved as:

You select the edge/face/node/element you want:

```
   edge = s.getByBoundingBox((0,0.02,0,0.003,0.04,0))
```

Create a intermediate variable to know the "ID" of the element:

```
   edge_id = edge.id
```

You now can refenciate it in the dialog for creating surfaces:

```
   p.Surface(side1Edges=p.edges[edge_id], name='r1')
```

**In this case, you're telling Abaqus to select the edge with the id "edge_id" from all the edges that your part "p" has.**

This happens many times and you've to be aware what Abaqus is expecting from the code. Sometimes can be the object itselft, a tuple of elements or simply a float expressed as a tupple e.g: edge = (number, )

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I tried the modified code on a 2D plate with the following code

```
p = mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Plate']
s = p.edges
edges=s.getByBoundingBox(0,0,0,25,25,1)
```

And it does not crash. But its not really clear how you can create a surface using this. You need to use a different strategy to achieve what you want. You can find create a surface using the 'pointOn' method.